# Не билдится сборка на webpack

Tags: webpack, npm

Выводит такую ошибку:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'main.js' in 'C:\gitRepos\remember\src'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! remember@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config config/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the remember@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Беда в том что по пути `C:\gitRepos\remember\src` лежит файл `main.js`.

Как будто какого то лоадера не хватает, который не может вытащить `main.js`.

Подключение в webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    entry: "./css/styles.less", 
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "./public/css",  
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    context: path.join(__dirname, "../src"),
    entry: "main.js",
    output: {   
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./public"),
        filename: "./js/app.js",
    },
    module: { 
      ...   
  }
}
```

Comment: Причем, если закомментировать подключение main.js то начинает ругаться на styles.less таким же образом..

Answer (score 0):

Знающий человек тыкнул меня лицом)) Внимательно перечитал документацию webpack'а, понял как затупил в его конфиге. Убрал множественные точки вхождения, переселил все файлы js и css для сборщика в одну папку. Подключение css вообще осуществил импортом в моей входной точке для сборщика: app.js. Облизанный конфиг выглядит теперь так:

```js
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
 context: path.join(__dirname, "../src"),
 entry: {
  main: "./main.js"
 }, 
 node: {
  fs: 'empty',
  net: 'empty'
 },
 output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, "../public"),
  filename: "./js/[name].js",
 },
 module: {
  rules: [{
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
   use: [{
    loader: "babel-loader",
    query: {
     presets: ["es2015"]
    }
   }]
  }, {
   test: /\.vue$/,
   exclude: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
   use: [{
    loader: "vue-loader"
   }]
  }, {
   test: /\.less$/,
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: "style-loader",
    use: ["css-loader", "less-loader"]
   })
  }]
 },
 plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: 'css/styles.css'  // а тут надо прописать имя css которое вы хотите
  })
 ],
 resolve: {
  alias: {
   vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
 }
}
```